# z-index wont work positions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve that the `erf_fromto` would have a higher `z-index` than `left_side`, cause `left_side` do have a border, while i want the `erf_fromto` to be over the border.

this is how it looks like currently, while I want the `erf_fromto` to be over the line.

[image]

```
  <body class="parent" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="left_side child"></div>
    <div class="right_side">
    <div class="erf_block" style="position:relative;">
            <div class="erf_fromto">2011 - 2012</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

css:

```
.left_side {
    width:35%;
    float:left;
    border-right: 3px solid #F6F6F6;
}

.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}


.child {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}


.erf_fromto {
    position: absolute;
    left: -122px;
    border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #F6F6F6;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjzwdN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` applies to an element and it's children. Since `.erf_fromto` is nested inside `.erf_block`, which is inside `.right_side` you'll want to ensure that it's `.right_side` that has the higher `z-index` than `.left_side`!

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of an element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

Comment: So the whole right side needs the Higher zindex? Not possible to Only do the element ?:)

Comment: Maybe have a go at it like this: http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/RGjOwo

I've made `.left_side` & `.right_side` into 50% halves, and did a `relative` / `absolute` positioning trick with `.erf_block` and `.parent`, in order to keep it from disrupting the flow of the other blocks. (I've also set `.erf_block` as a sibling to `.left_side` and `.right_side` in this pen.)

No z-index needed this way.

However, if my original answer clarified your original question, please mark it as accepted! :)

Comment: i tried to do z-index 2 in right side (position relative), and z-index 1 in left side, but the block wouldnt cover that element. how come?

Comment: Please share the current state in a codepen or similar. Maybe update the original q to reflect this.

Comment: Why not add "`background-color: white;`" to `.erf_fromto`? http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/PGOvGV Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

If you also put a position: relative; and z-index:0; to the .left_side child it will work

Comment: class child do have the absolute .

Answer (score 0):

Maria,

If you add a background to **left_side** and **erf_fromto** you will see they are on the correct position.

I think you just need add background property on your **erf_fromto** class:

```
.erf_fromto {
   ...
   background: white;
   ...
}
```

I hope it helps...

Good Luck!